# default access modifier for interface member

Tags: c#, oop

I'm new to C#, just a question on default access modifier for interface member. 
We know that the default access modifier for interface is "internal", but why the default access modifier for interface member is "public"? shouldn't it be "internal" so it can be consistent?

Comment: Access Modifiers are bound to what you want and how you want your code to behave. I don't think it's necessary what the default is, but the internal access modifier makes that interface accessible only within the project namespace within which it is defined. You have full control on how you want the members to behave.

Comment: `shouldn't it be "internal" so it can be consistent?` Given it would act exactly the same as a `public` method on a internal type - why does it matter to you? What would allowing you to explicitly specify `internal` do that you can't do right now?

Answer (score 1):

> `Interfaces` declared directly within a `namespace` can be declared as
>   `public` or `internal` and, just like `classes` and `structs`,
>   `interfaces` default to `internal` access. Interface members are always
>   `public` because the purpose of an `interface` is to enable other
>   types to access a `class` or `struct`. No access modifiers can be
>   applied to interface members.

For more information about **Access Modifiers (C# Programming Guide)** check the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers)